# Not able to write a Text on txt File using C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have tried to write a string on text file,but its not writing anything and there is no exceptions. My code is:

```
 public void CreateLog(string sLogInfo)
 {
    string sDestionation = null;

    string sFileName = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + "_log.txt";
    sDestionation = @"D:\Log\";
    //sDestionation = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DestinationPath"].ToString();
    string sFile = sDestionation + sFileName;

    if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(sDestionation))
    {
       System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(sDestionation);
    }
    StreamWriter oWriter = null;
    if (!System.IO.File.Exists(sFile))
    {
       oWriter = File.CreateText(sFile);
    }
    else
    {
       oWriter = File.AppendText(sFile);
    }
    oWriter.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString() + ": " + sLogInfo.Trim());
 }
```

Comment: What debugging have you done? I see no reason why you can't work this out yourself, or at least get further by debugging. It looks like you are stuck because you stopped trying before doing any debugging.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[StreamWriter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter(v=vs.110).aspx) is [IDisposable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable(v=vs.120).aspx) object. You should dispose it after using. For this you can use [`using`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02(v=VS.120).aspx) statement like this:

```
    public void CreateLog(string sLogInfo)
    {
        string sDestionation = null;

        string sFileName = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + "_log.txt";
        sDestionation = @"D:\Log\";
        var sFile = sDestionation + sFileName;

        if (!Directory.Exists(sDestionation))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(sDestionation);
        }
        using (var oWriter = new StreamWriter(sFile, true))
            oWriter.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + ": " + sLogInfo.Trim());
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [File.AppendAllText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143356%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that will do all the steps (except creating folder) for you.

Otherwise you should properly dispose writer when you are done, preferably with `using` in the same function:

```
using(oWriter)
{
  oWriter.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString() + ": " + sLogInfo.Trim());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code looks fine, however, I think you should add at the end of it the following:
`oWriter.Close()`

Answer (score 1):

You should <s>flush</s> (disposing is enough) your data into the file at the end of your code:
<s>`oWriter.Flush();`</s> `//Save (Clears all buffers for the current writer and causes any buffered data to be written to the underlying stream.)`

```
oWriter.Dispose(); //Then free this resource
```

As Yuval mentioned looking at C#'s StreamWriter.cs class it does indeed calls the `Flush` method internally. See here: [Reference](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/streamwriter.cs,250)

Comment: [`StreamWriter.Dispose`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/streamwriter.cs,9e38cb1c84769eba) is enough. It will call `Flush` internally.